# Restful site broke after upgrading resteasy-jaxrs to the lastest version

Tags: maven, resteasy

I'm going through this tutorial example on RestEasy:

```
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/
```

I downloaded their code and made modification so that I can deploy it to tomcat 7 and java 1.7.

If I leave the pom.xml as specified by the site,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

then everything appears to be fine and can be accessed through:

```
    http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/message/hello
```

However, if I were to increase the version level to 3.0.8.Final or "RELEASE",

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

then I can't access it via the above URL.  Instead, I get this message in my localhost_access_log.txt

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2014:16:02:55 -0700] "GET /RESTfulExample/rest/message/hello HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Question:  Does anyone know how I can get the pom.xml to work if I really want to use RESTeasy 3.0.8.Final?  I'm new to Rest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation describes](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e111) you can initialize RESTeasy in a standalone Servlet 3.0 compliant container by adding this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

You should also update the web.xml with the correct Servlet version. Most of the old configuration stuff can be removed so you end up with:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0"> 
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Last thing to do is tell RESTeasy on which path you want to map your application by adding `javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath` to the MessageApplication class:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MessageApplication extends Application { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: [ERROR] \code3\rest-mkyong\RESTfulExample\src\main\java\com\mkyong\app\MessageApplication.java:[10,1] error: cannot find symbol , and specifically, it's pointing at @ApplicationPath("/rest")

Comment: Did you `import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath`?

Comment: Lefloh:  How did you know how to fix the above when the library went from <version>2.2.1.GA</version> to version 3+ ?