# What needs to go inside the Application class?

Tags: java, tomcat, resteasy

Whats exactly needs to go inside the Application class?

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest") 
public class MessageApplication extends Application { ... }
```

What code goes inside (...)?

thanks

Reference to question :  [Restful site broke after upgrading resteasy-jaxrs to the lastest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394497/restful-site-broke-after-upgrading-resteasy-jaxrs-to-the-lastest-version/25410635#25410635)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html):

> Defines the components of a JAX-RS application and supplies additional meta-data.

You can overwrite `getClasses()`, `getSingletons()` and `getProperties()` and register e.g. your resource classes or providers.

You can also leave your application class empty and [let RESTeasy scan](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e125) for this classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer    

I did the same as suggested by you in your earlier link   

1. Left the Application class empty
2. Blank web.xml with servlet version 3.0    
3. Included resteasy-servlet-initializer with latest version 3.0.8.Final   
4. Deployed the war into JBoss AS 7    
5. Things works absolutely fine    

Problem arises only when I deploy the same war file with all required jars in Apache Tomcat 7.0.54 server     

I want to know, what changes are required to deploy war file into the Tomcat server to make it up & running   

TIA.

Comment: As already answered: You can *either* register your resource classes in your application class *or* you enable `resteasy.scan` in your web.xml. Leaving both empty won't work.

Comment: Leaving both empty and deploying in JBoss AS 7 works fine. Deploying same war file with required libraries in Tomcat-7.0.54 and adding resteasy.scan to your web.xml shows warning "resteasy.scan no longer supported. Use ServletContextInitializer with Servlet-3.0 version" Any Idea why this behaviour in tomcat-7.0.x ?

Comment: Maybe you try adding your classes to the application class.

Comment: To overcome this situation there are two ways, first as suggested by @lefloh add your JAX-RS classes to the application class this is one which extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application other way is to set <resteasy.resources>fully.qualified.your.class.name</resteasy.resources> in web.xml. Look at the JBoss resteasy documentation http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e125